# Perl: proper way to check ref of a hashref in one swoop?

Tags: perl, ref

Given Example Code:

```
foo(bar=>"test");
foo(bar=>["test"]);

sub foo {
   my $args = {@_};

   say ref($args->{bar});
   say ref(\$args->{bar});
}
```

Outputs:

> {expected blank}
>   SCALAR
>   ARRAY
>   REF

---

What I would like to test for is the best way to check if what is passed is a scalar or an array.  Something like:

```
given( ref($args->{bar}) ){
   when "SCALAR" { }
   when "ARRAY"  { }
}
```

I could concatenate the two ref types and do a regex-when, but that's inefficient.  I could also test it like the following, but not sure if that's preferred:

```
if    ( ref(\$args->{bar}) eq "SCALAR" ) { ... }
elsif ( ref( $args->{bar}) eq "ARRAY"  ) { ... }
else  { return; }
```

Comment: I don't see the compelling reason not to do something simple like `if (!ref $args->{bar}) { # scalar case } elsif ("ARRAY" eq ref $args->{bar}) { # handle array}`.

Comment: @MoritzBunkus: I think that might be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not trying to differentiate between a scalar and an array. You get a scalar in both cases. You're trying to differentiate between a non-reference and a reference to an array.

```
if (!ref($x) || ref($x) eq 'ARRAY') {
   # Non-ref or ref to array.
   ...
}
```

or

```
if (!ref($x)) {
   # Non-ref
   ...
}
elsif (ref($x) eq 'ARRAY') {
   # Ref to array.
   ...
}
```

or

```
for (ref($x)) {
   if (!$_) {
      # Non-ref
      ...
   }
   elsif ($_ eq 'ARRAY') {
      # Ref to array.
      ...
   }
}
```

or

```
my $ref_type = ref($x);
if (!$ref_type) {
   # Non-ref
   ...
}
elsif ($ref_type eq 'ARRAY') {
   # Ref to array.
   ...
}
```

or (assuming those are the only two types of values allowed)

```
if (ref($x)) {
   # Ref to array.
   ...
} else {
   # Non-ref
   ...
}
```

(Note that Scalar::Util's `reftype` actually gets the ref type. `ref` can return a class name instead of a reference type.)

Note that differentiating values based on storage type is a poor design in Perl. It necessarily buggy, since it breaks overloaded objects.

Answer (score 1):

Given a pragma in scope of

```
use feature qw/ say switch /;
```

you could use

```
sub foo {
  my($args) = { @_ };

  given (ref $args->{bar}) {
    say "plain scalar '$args->{bar}'"
      when "";

    say "array, length=@{[scalar @{ $args->{bar} }]}"
      when "ARRAY";

    default { die "unexpected: $args->{bar}" }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
plain scalar 'test'
array, length=1
```

Your question is abstract, but with more knowledge of what you want to do, we can offer more specific and helpful suggestions for your particular situation.